# Android SQLiteOpenHelper time-consuming onCreate, need progress bar on first run

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

The first time my app runs it creates a database in which it loads 6,000 rows from a file in `/res/raw`.  I can't do this asynchronously as the app depends on it entirely. It runs rapidly on my phone - a Moto X - but it's really slow in all my emulators and I'm concerned it could be a bit slower on slower devices thus making the user stare at a blank screen for a few seconds before the app does anything.

Is there a way to put a progress bar while running the overrided `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s `onCreate()` methood and have it update the progress bar with how far along it is, with a message saying something like "Initializing data for first use!"?

Comment: Why don't you ship the app with a precreated database file?

Comment: @CL is that possible ? Can you recommend any tutorials or blogs.... Im hearing for the first time

Comment: @CL - that's not possible. The only way to do this is to ship said .db file, and literally open it and copy it byte by byte (buffered blah blah) on onCreate, you gain nothing or very little compared to the SQL loading approach.

Comment: Copying a single block of data is likely to be faster (and simpler) than creating the database structure on the fly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by starting an `AsyncTask` in `onCreate` and then only loading the layout at the end of the 'AsyncTask` (or if the data had previously been loaded). It works beautifully as a loading screen. I followed this tutorial http://www.41post.com/4588/programming/android-coding-a-loading-screen-part-1 (which explains the details more) then changed it a bit for my needs (such as loading a raw resource).

I should say that although it does it asynchronously because the main layout hasn't loaded the user has to wait for the loading to complete before he or she can continue, so hopefully that means it doing it asynchronously won't be a problem for you with the app depending on the database.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
       dataAddedToDB = (sharedPref.getBoolean(PXS_RXS_UPDATE, false));

       if (!dataAddedToDB) {
        new LoadViewTask(this).execute();
       } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }
    }
```

In the `AsyncTask` it loads the database showing how far it has got and showing your message and then only goes on to show the layout at the end. (BTW, it is helpful to lock the screen orientation while doing this to stop it messing it up).

EDIT: `publishProgress(counter);` passes the value of where the task has got to to `onProgressUpdate()`.

```
    private class LoadViewTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    private Context context;
    public LoadViewTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Initializing data for first use!");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        // this counts how many line to be added to the database so it can later tell how far it has got.
        final Resources resources2 = context.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream2 = resources2.openRawResource(R.raw.rawherbaldata);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream2));
        int lineCount = 0;

        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineCount++;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        progressDialog.setMax(lineCount);
        progressDialog.setProgress(0);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HerbalDatabaseOpenHelper mHerbalDbHelper = new HerbalDatabaseOpenHelper(MainActivity.this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mHerbalDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        int counter = 0;

        final Resources resources2 = context.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream2 = resources2.openRawResource(R.raw.rawherbaldata);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream2));

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            int lineNumber = 1;
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            // CODE FOR ENTERING LINE INTO DATABASE         

            // EDIT: the following keeps the task updated on where it has got to, passing the count to onProgressUpdate()
            counter++;
            publishProgress(counter);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
        db.close();

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        pxsRxsUpdate = true;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(PXS_RXS_UPDATE, pxsRxsUpdate);
        editor.commit();

        // initialize the View
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Comment: WOW! yes that is working!  Thanks!  One thing though: what do you do to invoke `onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)` ?

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint ah yes sorry, in editing the code for the post I accidentally deleted it. Each time `int counter` is increased you'll need `publishProgress(counter);` then it should work. Will update my answer.

Comment: I build the dialog myself! Didn't know there is a class for that :) +1 (DialogFragment with AlertDialog).

Answer (score 2):

You could use another intermediate activity which would show the progress dialog and then send you back to the main activity when done.

First you'll need a static method that a boolean if the DB has already been create.

Then inside of your activity's `onCreate` call the middleman if necessary:

```
DbHelper mDbHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (!DbHelper.isDbCreated()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DbActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        return;
    }
    // Do normal stuff like instantiating the helper and so on
    mDbHelper = new DbHelper();
    ...
}
```

Then inside of this "middleman" activity show the ProgressDialog and create the database.

Once you're done, hide the dialog and go back to your main activity:

```
mProgress.dismiss();

Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

finish();
return;
```

If your static method `isDbCreated()` is created properly, you won't reveal the MainActivity's content until the database is created.

**EDIT:**

Here's the method I use to check for the database. Perhaps it will help you.

```
public boolean isDbCreated() {
    String sDatabasePath = context.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getPath();
    SQLiteDatabase tmpDb = null;

    if (mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).exists()) {
        try {
            tmpDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(sDatabasePath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            tmpDb.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "DB file doesn't exist.");
        // If the parent dir doesn't exist, create it
        File parentDir = new File(mContext.getDatabasePath(DB_NAME).getParent());
        if (!parentDir.exists()) {
            if (parentDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Successfully created the parent dir:" + parentDir.getName());
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create the parent dir:" + parentDir.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    return (tmpDb != null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but man that's a lot of work!  I was hoping that I could somehow make my MainActivity pop up a dialog before instantiating the on DbHelper and then destroy it when it comes back.

Comment: Okay I need to do what you suggested (darn!)  But what should the isDbCreate() method look like?

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint there are a few possibilities. For example you could set a shared preference once your database is created. Or you could check if the database file exists. I'll post the method I'm using. However I copy the database file and use this method differently :)

Comment: Thanks for the full method!  But, groan, what is `sDatabasePath` supposed to be set to?  I can figure it out from here then I think. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint whoops! Updated with the definition. The reason it's defined outside is because I also use it for opening the database.

Comment: Thanks!  The check works, now to write the Activity. Typo in your code btw: forgot to make the method `static` :-)  Also are you sure that we're supposed to `return;` after `finish()`ing the `Intent`? Will the `startActivity()` "block" there or is it asynchronous? Sorry if that's a stupid question, I'm new at this.

Comment: @PhilippeLePoint the return is only to prevent further code in that specific method to be executed and you are `finish()`ing not the intent but the initial activity. And by the way, as I said I use the method differently so it's not static. I've put it here just for reference.